# How to open ssl socket in already opened SSL Session java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have HttpsURLConnection opened.
How can i "connect" my ssl socket to this connection, means not to do another ssl handshake and don't change my ciphers.

```
URL url = new URL ("https://example.com:8080");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

SSLSocketFactory ssf = connection.getSSLSocketFactory();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket("example.com", 8080);
```

// and here i want to send message with socket which will be in the same ssl session as https connection.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
out.write("Hello");
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Is it really to do such thing in Java?

Comment: I assume `s` in the second block is really `socket` and I note 8080 is an unusual and confusing port for HTTPS much less non-HTTP+SSL/TLS as your second block seems to be doing.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: port 8080 is commonly used by routers and proxies and such.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: i know about port 443, just give this example. this is not my question. yes sorry s as socket :-D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot attach a new socket to the existing SSL session.  If you want to send/read data on the original SSL session, use the original socket connection created by the `URLConnection` object.  You can use the [`URLConnection.getInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()) and [`URLConnection.getOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getoutputStream()) methods to get the input/output streams for it:

```
URL url = new URL ("https://example.com:8080");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

...

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
out.write("Hello");
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: Java will do session sharing by default. Try it.

Comment: @Vik: why? What are you really trying to accomplish?  It almost sounds like you are connecting to an arbitrary TCP server via an HTTPS proxy, and then want to send arbitrary data after the connection is established.  Is that the case?  Or are you actually communicating with a real HTTPS server instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, sorry, i have found another problem. my task was to send different https requests in single ssl session, i thing that the answer is just to send requests from the same source port.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can i send multiple messages in one connection with this method that you provided?

Answer (score 1):

It should happen that way by default, as long as the session remains valid, and provided you haven't messed around with `SSLContexts.`

Comment: And the server assigned a sessionid and did cache; nearly all do.

Comment: And conversely if the server didn't assign and cache a sessionID there is no session to resume so it's impossible. @dave_thompson_085